# Ember js link to the parent record

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am creating a simple app using Ember showing manager and reportee hierarchy.
The link to button should lend me to the manager's page , and i want to display it in the same template as its reportee , as the manager is also one of the employee. Can anyone suggest how to do this.

App.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create(
{
LOG_TRANSITION:true
}
);

App.Router.map(function() {
 this.route("employees");
 this.resource('employee' , { path:"/employee/:employee_id"});

App.EmployeesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
var emp = [];
for ( var i in App.Employees){
    emp.push(App.Employees[i]);
}
    return emp;
}
});

App.Employee = Ember.Object.extend( {
"id": null ,
"empid": null ,
"name" : null ,
"age" : null ,
"sex": null ,
"dob" : null ,
"email": null ,
"phone": null ,
"address": null ,
"manager": null ,
"manager-id" : null ,
"department" : null ,
"designation" : null
})
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">
   <h1 align="center">Ember WorkShop Accolite AU</h1>
   {{outlet}}
 </script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
   <ul>
   {{#each item in model}}
     <li>{{item}}</li>
   {{/each}}
   </ul>
 </script>
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="employees">
 <table>
 <tr bgcolor=lightblue> 
 <td>NAME</td><td>EMP-ID</td><td>AGE</td><td>SEX</td><td>DOB</td><td>E-MAIL</td><td>PHONE</td><td>MANAGER</td></tr>
   {{#each emp in model }}
   {{this.manager_id}}

<tr>
<td class= "span1"> {{#linkTo 'employee' emp }}{{emp.name}}{{/linkTo}}</td>
 <td class="span1">{{#linkTo 'employee' emp}}{{emp.empid}}{{/linkTo}}</td>
 <td class="span1"> {{emp.age}}</td>
 <td class="span1"> {{emp.sex}}</td>
 <td class="span2"> {{emp.dob}}</td>
 <td class="span2"> {{emp.email}}</td>
 <td class="span2"> {{emp.phone}}</td>
 <td class="span1"> {{emp.manager}}</td>
 </tr>

   {{/each}}
 <tr bgcolor = lightblue>
 <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
 </tr>
   </table>
 </script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="employee">
   {{#linkTo 'employees'}} BackButton {{/linkTo}}</br>
     EMPID : {{empid}} </br>
     Name : {{name}} </br>
     Age : {{age}} </br>
     DOB : {{dob}} </br>
     Gender : {{sex}} </br>
     Email: {{email}} </br>
     Phone: {{phone}} </br>
     Address: {{address}}</br>
     Manager : {{manager}}</br>
     Department: {{department}} </br>
     Designation: {{designation}} </br>

 <br><br>
 </script>
 <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js"></script>
 <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0-rc.6.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="js/employees.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

employees.js

```
App.Employees ={

"1" : App.Employee.create ({
    "id" : "1" ,
    "empid" :  "id1", 
    "name"  : "Maxwell",
    "age" : "53" ,
    "sex" : "M",
    "dob" : "23-4-1978" ,
    "email" : "max@accolite.com"  ,
    "phone" : "765873687" ,
    "address" : "Seattle" ,
    "manager" : "None" ,
    "manager-id" : "None" ,
    "department" : "core-tech" ,
    "designation" : "tech"
    }) ,


"2" : App.Employee.create ({
    "id" : "2" ,
    "empid" :  "id2", 
    "name"  : "peter",
    "age" : "35" ,
    "sex" : "M",
    "dob" : "2-3-1998" ,
    "email" : "p@accolite.com"  ,
    "phone" : "765873687" ,
    "address" : "hine" ,
    "manager" : "none" ,
    "manager-id" : "2" ,
    "department" : "core-tech" ,
    "designation" : "tech"
    }) ,

"3" : App.Employee.create ({
    "id" : "3" ,
    "empid" :  "id3", 
    "name"  : "John",
    "age" : "23" ,
    "sex" : "M",
    "dob" : "30-4-1988" ,
    "email" : "john@accolite.com"  ,
    "phone" : "765873687" ,
    "address" : "mountain view" ,
    "manager" : "peter" ,
    "manager-id" : "87" ,
    "department" : "core-tech" ,
    "designation" : "techie"
    }) ,


"4" : App.Employee.create ({
    "id" : "4" ,
    "empid" :  "id4", 
    "name"  : "hitler",
    "age" : "35" ,
    "sex" : "M",
    "dob" : "23-4-1978" ,
    "email" : "p@g.com"  ,
    "phone" : "765873687" ,
    "address" : "hine" ,
    "manager" : "John" ,
    "manager-id" : "2" ,
    "department" : "core-tech" ,
    "designation" : "tech"
    }) , 

"5" : App.Employee.create ({
    "id" : "5" ,
    "empid" :  "id5", 
    "name"  : "Elson",
    "age" : "23" ,
    "sex" : "M",
    "dob" : "23-4-1978" ,
    "email" : "m@accolite.com"  ,
    "phone" : "765873687" ,
    "address" : "hine" ,
    "manager" : "peter" ,
    "manager-id" : "87" ,
    "department" : "core-tech" ,
    "designation" : "tech"
    }) ,


"6" : App.Employee.create ({
    "id" : "6" ,
    "empid" :  "id6", 
    "name"  : "Victor",
    "age" : "35" ,
    "sex" : "M",
    "dob" : "23-4-1978" ,
    "email" : "v@accolite.com"  ,
    "phone" : "765873687" ,
    "address" : "hine" ,
    "manager" : "none" ,
    "manager-id" : "2" ,
    "department" : "core-tech" ,
    "designation" : "tech"
    }) ,

"7" : App.Employee.create ({
    "id" : "7" ,
    "empid" :  "id7", 
    "name"  : "Gennedy",
    "age" : "83" ,
    "sex" : "M",
    "dob" : "23-4-1978" ,
    "email" : "john@accolite.com"  ,
    "phone" : "765873687" ,
    "address" : "mountain view" ,
    "manager" : "peter" ,
    "manager-id" : "87" ,
    "department" : "core-tech" ,
    "designation" : "techie"
    }) ,


"8" : App.Employee.create ({
    "id" : "8" ,
    "empid" :  "id8", 
    "name"  : "Lisa",
    "age" : "35" ,
    "sex" : "F",
    "dob" : "23-4-1978" ,
    "email" : "p@accolite.com"  ,
    "phone" : "888873687" ,
    "address" : "hine" ,
    "manager" : "John" ,
    "manager-id" : "2" ,
    "department" : "core-tech" ,
    "designation" : "tech"
    }) 
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code you have so far?

Comment: @BradleyPriest code pasted. here i wants to display the manager details once the associated employee get's clicked.

Answer (score 0):

you can find manager record for a particular employee `emp` and pass it as reference to `{{linkTo}}` helper. This can be done by using [computed properties](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) or you can use [ember-data associations](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/).

Comment: PLz Check the code , on clicking the empid i am getting th emp details , and I have kept the manager-id as one of the attribute of employee , which itself is a employee id , and on clicking the manager tag , the details of that id show get displayed. How computed properties would help here ?

Comment: Have a look at the #linkTo helper you are getting correctly {{#linkTo 'employee' emp }}. In this `emp` is the expression/variable that is used as reference model for next route. This is why when you click on id or name, you get the details corresponding to passed `emp` record. using computed property you can pass something like emp.manager which should work.

Comment: #linkTo is working for that particular employee only , but how to keep the manager's state and display it .

Comment: create a computed property or association named say `manager` in emp record. which when you try accessing like `emp.manager` gives the manager object/record. and then pass that as context to linkTo like this {{#linkto 'employee' emp.manager}}{{emp.manager}}{{/linkTo}}